# Расширить root в Centos 7 (VM VMware)

Tags: centos7, lvm

история:
после увеличения диска через Gparted стало так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как расширить centos-root? долблюсь в гайды, но везде получается что свободного места нет

Тема стара как мир, понимаю... но уже устал, да и давно не связывался с подобным

Answer (score 0):

в общем, вчера протупил. оставалось просто сделать `xfs_growfs -d /dev/mapper/centos-root`

вопрос закрыт